# range restriction/domain restriction in Isabelle

Tags: set, range, symbols, restriction, isabelle

I am trying to input a schema into Isabelle however when I add range restriction or domain restriction into the theorem prover it doesn't want to parse. I have the following schema in LaTeX:

```
\begin{schema}{VideoShop}
members: \power PERSON \\
rented: PERSON \rel TITLE \\
stockLevel: TITLE \pfun \nat
\where
\dom rented \subseteq members \\
\ran rented \subseteq \dom stockLevel \\
\forall t: \ran rented @ \# (rented \rres \{t\}) \leq stockLevel~t
\end{schema}
```

When inputting this into Isabelle I get the following:

```
locale videoshop = 
fixes members :: "PERSON set"
and rented :: "(PERSON * TITLE) set"
and stockLevel :: "(TITLE * nat) set"
assumes "Domain rented \<subseteq> members" 
 and "Range rented \<subseteq> Domain stockLevel" 
 and "(\<forall> t. (t \<in> Range rented) \<and> (card (rented \<rhd> {t}) \<le> stockLevel t))"
begin
.....
```

It all parses except for the last expression `\<forall> t.....`

I just don't understand how to add range restriction into Isabelle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your input.

1. The `⊳` symbol you are using in the expression

   ```
   (rented ⊳ {t})
   ```

   is not associated with any operator, so it can't be parsed. I'm not quite sure what it's supposed to mean. From the high-level idea of the specification I'm guessing something along the lines of "all persons who rented a specific title". This can be expressed most easily with a set comprehension:

   ```
   {p. (p, t) ∈ rented}
   ```
2. You translated the bounded universal quantifier into a quantifier containing a conjunction. This is likely not what you want, because it says "for all `t`, `t` is in the range of `rented` *and* something else". Isabelle has notation for bounded quantifiers.

   ```
   ∀t ∈ Range rented. ...
   ```
3. You are trying to use `stockLevel` as a function, which it isn't. From your LaTeX input I gather that it's supposed to be a partial function. Isabelle calls these `map`s. The appropriate type is:

   ```
   TITLE ⇀ nat
   ```

   Note the "harpoon" symbol instead of a function arrow. The domain function for maps is called `dom`. The second locale assumption can be expressed as:

   ```
   Range rented ⊆ dom stockLevel
   ```

   Given that, you can use `stockLevel` as a function from `TITLE` to `nat option`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. What is the syntax to get the nat option for stockLevel? I've changed the \<forall> expression to "(\<forall> t  \<in> Range rented. card ({p. (p, t) \<in> rented}) < (stockLevel t))" but theres a clash of types with the (stockLevel t)

Comment: `stockLevel t` gives you a `nat option`. To convert that to `nat`, you can use the `the` function: `the (stockLevel t)`.

Comment: Another quick question, say i wanted to update the stockLevel so I had the expression stockLevel' = stockLevel \cup (t \mapsto n).  How would i write that in Isabelle syntax, I've looked at the maps_add function but i don't quite get it and i don't know if thats what i need. @larsrh

Comment: Is `stockLevel` a function now, or still a set?

Comment: It is a function using the ⇀ sign @larsrh

Comment: Try this: `stockLevel(t ↦ n)`